# Set reading order of a pdf to (right to left, top to bottom) using pdfbox or itext in java

Tags: itext, pdfbox

[image]

Hi folks i am looking for a programmatic solution to set the reading order of a document, from (left to right) To (right to left).
Do we have an option to do that using pdfbox or itext , if yes can any one produce the coding snippet for the same,
Thanks
Tejas